# Can I get SQL error details programmatically? (in .Net and SQL Server)

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server

The example I'm hitting is that I'm attempting to update a record in a database and I get a violation of a unique value constraint. The text of the message has the name of the constraint and the value that is duplicated. In principle, I could parse the text of the message to extract this information. But I hate to do that, because text processing like that has a tendency to add ambiguities. Like, the value is enclosed in parentheses. But if I search the text for parentheses, what if parentheses occur somewhere else in the message, like someone created a constraint name with parentheses in it or some such? What if future releases of the DB engine change the wording or format of the message? Etc. So is this information available in cleanly-defined fields?

(Specifically I'm using VB.Net but I presume any answer would apply to .Net in general.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Processing the text data of the exception is the only way to do this currently. Granular information doesn't come back in the exception.

While it would be nice to have this information come back, there's usually not a whole lot that can be done about it from within code. Issues like simple foreign key violations should be accounted for in business logic to begin with, so things like this should be exceptional cases where you should provide the user with some way to deliver as much of the error message to the development team, anyway.

Comment: It's the only way to do this, and it's a bad way to do this, so the answer is to not need to do this.

Comment: RE: can't be done: bummer, but thanks for the info. As to why I want to know: 1. Give the user a prettier error message, like "The social security number you are trying to enter is already assigned to another employee" rather than "TSQL Error 2967 unique constraint violation on constraint UQ__2390320923093" or however that text goes. 2. Depending on the business logic, there are times when you could do something about it, like replace the offending field with a default value perhaps.

Comment: @Jay: I hear what you're saying, and it is a "nice to have", but there's really not a lot of obvious value in having it. The examples you list are easily accounted for in business logic. It's generally a bad idea to rely on the database to do your user input validation, as the database constraints are the last stop that ensures the integrity of your data. If bad data reaches the database, the software's already broken and at that point you need to start presenting the user with the information they'll need to give you when they call for support.

Comment: Not to get into a debate on this point, but: Yes, in most cases I could write business logic to do such a validation. But that would mean repeating the constraint in application code, which violates DRY. Also, in the case that prompted this question, I'm trying to write some generic code that can be used not just for multiple tables but for multiple projects, i.e. I want to take this same function and just drop it in another project and it works without having to customize it with the constraints for this particular db and table.

Comment: @Jay: Such constraints are almost *always* repeated in application code. It's not a violation of DRY, because they're different: one (the database) is intended to make absolutely sure that the data in your database is 100% consistent, regardless of the user experience required to make that happen. The other (your business logic) is designed to ensure that the correct data is sent to the database and provide the user with an appropriate way of either avoiding or correcting input errors. I understand what you're saying, but people have been round and round about whether or not...

Comment: ...database constraints should be reproduced in business logic, and the result has always been a pretty resounding "yes" for all of the reasons put forth in this question. In your case, if you're really trying to make something so generic that you don't know what tables (or even structure) that you're dealing with, then you're going to be forced to parse out the text, examine the metadata in the database to figure out what (in the case of FK violations) fields the constraint references, then turn that into something hopefully more meaningful to the user.